# JogAmp gluegen-rt can't find native library

Tags: java, eclipse, native, jogl, jzy3d

I'm on OSX 10.7.5, Eclipse 3.8.0, using JDK 1.7. I'm trying to build a project using jzy3d and JogAmp: particularly jogl, gluegen, and gluegen-rt.

I've followed this tutorial for setting up a user library for JOGL in my java project. 
https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE

I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/brendengarrison/Documents/workspace/jzy3d-15/natives/macosx-universal//gluegen-rt 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795) 
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062) 
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:624) 
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63) 
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:106) 
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:487) 
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:421) 
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:317) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:287) 
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:147) 
    at org.jzy3d.chart.Settings.detectProfile(Settings.java:30) 
    at org.jzy3d.chart.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:14) 
    at org.jzy3d.chart.Settings.getInstance(Settings.java:47) 
    at org.jzy3d.analysis.AnalysisLauncher.open(AnalysisLauncher.java:17) 
    at org.jzy3d.analysis.AnalysisLauncher.open(AnalysisLauncher.java:13) 
    at Test15.main(Test15.java:18)
```

My gluegen-rt-2.3.3.jar, gluegen-2.3.2.jar, and jogl-all-2.3.2.jar are in a folder called /jzy3d-newDependencies, as are my natives: gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar and jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar.

I left the natives out of the classpath, as instructed by the tutorial, but I'm not sure if I understood the instructions given that I'm receiving this error message. Where do I need to put the natives so that gluegen-rt can find them?

Comment: I haven't actively used/set up JOGL for a while, but .. doesn't it work when you **do** add the `...natives` JARs to the classpath?

Comment: I did try that but got the same error message. It's possible that there's an underlying problem, which presents the same error regardless of whether it finds the library or not. The error message says it can't load the library, not that it can't find it... So, do you know how I could investigate further?

Comment: It also says "Can't load" when it should actually say "Can't find" (the error message is distressingly unspecific). You seem to have solved it now? (The best thing will probably be to let Maven figure all this out, this usually works best (or at least, easier than manually collecting the required JARs...))

Comment: @Marco13 The JARs containing the Java libraries must be located into the same directory than the JARs containing the native libraries so that GlueGen finds and loads them even though the latter JARs don't need to be in the classpath as they contain no class.

Comment: @gouessej OK... I wonder where the necessity comes from to place them into the same *directory*. I'd think that Java "does not know about directories" (or the file system) when it comes to JARs. When the JARs are on the classpath, the natives could be loaded as resources. (At least, that's what I did in JCuda and JOCL, e.g. at https://github.com/gpu/JOCL/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jocl/LibUtils.java#L215 ). But I haven't studied the details of the JOGL/GlueGen native lib handling yet.

Comment: @Marco13 You should ask this question to Sven Göthel or Mickael Bien. As far as I know, we (JogAmp) have to support multiple deployment kinds, there are probably some security and performance aspects to consider.

Comment: @gouessej I thought that Michael Bien is no longer active in JogAmp... but however, in doubt, I can derive the first info from the source code, and could ask about details in the forum, issue tracker or here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was using JogAmp 2.3.2, I had to use the updated natives for 2.3.2, which can be downloaded here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C2%7Cjogamp

Jzy3d comes with outdated natives.

Comment: Where did you get this version of Jzy3D with outdated native libraries? A particular version of Jzy3D matches with a particular version of JOGL. You can't combine any version of Jzy3D with any version of JOGL. Moreover, you don't need gluegen, you need gluegen-rt.

Comment: By the way, the Java libraries must match with the native libraries too.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded Jzy3D from github but I downloaded the natives from the Jzy3D website. They were the only natives on the website, so I mistakenly assumed that they worked with any version of Jzy3D.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying now to run this project from my windows virtual machine. The natives worked for mac, but on the windows machine the Jzy3D graphics won't load. I think the windows natives aren't loading because the same thing was happening on my mac when I was having trouble with the mac natives. My machine is 64 bit windows with 64 bit JRE and 64 bit windows native from the link above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of JZy3D do you use? I advise you to use the very latest source code to build it and to use it with JOGL 2.3.2. If you want to make things easier for you, use jogamp-fat.jar instead of numerous JARs for the Java and native libraries.